# Split line into key-value pairs based on first string

Tags: text-processing

I want to know if there is an easy way to split a line in a file into multiple lines, such as this:

I have

```
A B C
1 2 3 4
```

And I want to get something like this, based on the first string of the line:

```
A B
A C
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

Basically based on the first string in the line create multiple lines with the second and third and fourth string and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here goes

```
awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) print $1, $i}' file
A B
A C
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```sh
printf %s\\n 'A B C' '1 2 3 4'|
sed -e's/\([^ ]*\)  *[^ ]*/&\n\1/;//P;D'
```

---

```
A B
A C
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

That works. It selects the first two sequences of zero or more not-space characters which are separated by one or more spaces. The first such sequence is referenced in `\1` and the whole selection in `&`. The selection is replaced with itself followed by a `\n`ewline then `\1`. Pattern space is then printed up to the first occurring newline, and then the same portion is `D`eleted before the pattern space is recycled to the top of the script with what remains.

You can see what it does with the `l`ook command. Replace the `P` w/ `l` and put another `l` before the `s///`ubstitution...

---

```
A B C$
A B\nA C$
A C$
A C\nA$
A$
1 2 3 4$
1 2\n1 3 4$
1 3 4$
1 3\n1 4$
1 4$
1 4\n1$
1$
```

---

```sh
printf %s\\n 'A B C' '1 2 3 4'|
sed -ne:t -e'/  *[^ ]*/{s//\n&/2;P;s///;} -ett
```

---

```
A B
A C
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

It matches a pattern space with at least one sequence of space characters and any trailing not-spaces. The first substitution inserts a newline before the second occurrence of such a sequence, then `P`rints up to the newline, and the second substitution removes the first occurrence of that pattern - which will also now include the newline the first one appended to the tail of that sequence when operating on the second. The `t`est branches back to the `:t` label each time a substitution occurs, and so `sed` eats pattern space a space separated field at a time.

With `l`ook again:

---

```
A B C$
A B\n C$
A C$
A C$
1 2 3 4$
1 2\n 3 4$
1 3 4$
1 3\n 4$
1 4$
1 4$
```

Answer (score 1):

using bash -

```
    while read x ; do set $x ; first=$1 ; shift; for i in $* ; do echo $first  $1; shift; done  ; done  < /tmp/1
    A B
    A C
    1 2
    1 3
    1 4
```

Comment: What does `set $x` do? This code may work, but explaining why will help more than just dumping it.

Comment: set is a shell builtin command.  args to set are available to the shell as positional parameters - more details under the "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" part of the bash manual. The script loops over lines in the input file and reads each line (eg., A B C..) and does a "set" to make these available as $1 , $2 etc. to the shell. It then loops over all the parameters ($*) and prints the first one each time followed by the the next (this is $1). shift is used to shift the parameters to the left so that $2 becomes $1, then $3 and so on.

Comment: [Avoid using `while read` when processing text.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)