# Copy First Column Id to different lines

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with multiple information in different columns to the same ID

```
first | x | y | z
second | x | y
third | x
```

I want something like this:

```
first | x
first | y
first | z
second | x
second | y
third | x
```

Comment: You'll want to look into the `awk` command, Linux's built-in column-parser.

Comment: Noticed after answering: Nearly exact dupe of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253954/127903

Comment: @don_crissti: What is the procedure here? We flag as dupe, and delete our comments and answers? I saw, that you already edited the other one.

Comment: @don_crissti: I flagged as dupe too, and deleted my answer. The other Q has something similar to my awk solution as AA anyway, and a longer explanation for the trick you used :)